# Using If function in VBA code to format charts

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have what I hope is a relatively simple request.

I am working on a macro which will automatically format a large number of charts that I am creating. I have got a problem, however, in that the number of series that each chart contains varies a lot.

If I try to run my current code on a chart that only has four series, for example, it errors when it reaches the code below and cannot process the code thereafter, as it is expecting a fifth series to format. I believe I need to implement code that says - "IF the chart has a fifth series THEN apply this next line of the macro".

The code below is that which I am using to format each series. How should this be encased within an if statement as described above?

```
ActiveChart.LegEND.Select
ActiveChart.LegEND.LegendEntries(5).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 1.5
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Count` member of the `SeriesCollection` collection ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822931.aspx)), this returns the number of series in the chart. You could use something like:

```
ActiveChart.LegEND.Select

If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 5 Then

    ActiveChart.LegEND.LegendEntries(5).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
         .Visible = msoTrue
         .Weight = 1.5
    End With
End If
```

This will only work if you have exactly 5 series, if you have more then the `Count` evaluates to say, 6, the above formatting would not be applied.

You can change the If statement slightly to the following:

```
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count >= 5 Then

    ActiveChart.LegEND.LegendEntries(5).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
         .Visible = msoTrue
         .Weight = 1.5
    End With

End If
```

You can then repeat this block in your code for >= 6 and it should work. On a side note, this is probably not the most efficient way to code this as you are repeating blocks of code, but that's not really the point of this question.

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I had in mind. However if I apply this Count function to the formatting code for each series and I have, for example, 20 series', the formatting doesn't get applied to any series other than the 20th one.

Because, naturally, any graph that has 20 is also going to have a count of 1,2,3,4... and so on.

I think this code is almost what I need though.